# C# Microsoft Office Developer help, tutorials, examples

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-office

As a developer I get different assignments and my current one involves interaction with Microsoft Office from C# - which I haven't been doing for a long time now. Having previously developed websites using ASP.NET, I found the site [www.asp.net/learn](http://www.asp.net/learn) very helpful.

Is there a similar site concerning Visual Studio vs. Microsoft Office development?

Comment: With respect, why didn't you immediately think to look on MSDN? The link is right there on http://msdn.microsoft.com/, in the list of developer centers. I'm truly curious why you and others don't go to MSDN as the first source of info on Microsoft Developer technologies (not the last source, just the first).

Comment: @John: - even though this might get me a downvote - , you know your asking for too much, he'd have to type "msdn.microsoft.com" , then use his eyes -or ctrl+f if his willing to type more!- to find the appropriate link,unless Microsoft -as usual- are calling it some acronym like VSTO,which -surprisingly-  in this case they are not-, still too much effort , it is much easier -IMO- to go to stackoverflow.com and post the question :)

Comment: This is not a case of lazyness - I have been diving into the MSDN several times before asking here. MSDN is a fine and very comprehensive library, but I would like to hear what other users prefer when doing this kind of stuff - lots of valuable information is common knowledge with the users of these technologies :)

Comment: @Chau: i wasn't indicating that you are lazy, believe me, just being generally sarcastic.. and what i said above is what i exactly do -YES i ask/or find the same question on SO even after i read from MSDN- because this website is becoming a very useful repository .by the way +1 for asking the question after reading from MSDN :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This  [article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/6260/developing-for-office-2007/) can help you get familiar the technologies used for developing office application generally (and specially 2007 and 2010).

Have you checked out VSTO > Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office

- [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx)
- [VSTO on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx)
- [VSTO Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto2/)
- [Office developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/default.aspx)

[.Net for office blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/eric_carter/)

[johnrdurant Blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/johnrdurant/default.aspx) writes alot of Office-Development related posts, using different technologies

This  [book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321334884)  was really useful for me, when i was trying to develop a C# application that interacts with Excel (it also explains interaction with most of the other Office applications )

Comment: @Madi D: In the beginning I thought that VSTO wasn't what I was looking for. But now I see, that precisely VSTO is what I have used and so far it works great. It would still be great to have a site like www.asp.net/learn for developing against MS Office =)